# Tic Tac Toe, Help/Determine Winner

Tags: c#, console

I'm creating a TicTacToe class that contains a 3 by 3 rectangular array of integers & is played by 2 human players. "1" is used for the first player's move & "2" is used for the second player's move. Currently, I am stuck and have no clue on how to determine/check whether the game has been won or whether its a draw after each and every move has been made.

Unfortunately, I'm stuck in checking if the game is won or drawn after each player makes a move & was hoping someone could help.

This is my code thus far:
Main class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TicTacToe game = new TicTacToe();
            game.PrintBoard();
            game.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

TicTacToe class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class TicTacToe
    {
        private const int BOARDSIZE = 3; //size of the board
        private int[,] board = new int [BOARDSIZE,BOARDSIZE]; // board representation
        string player1row, player1column, player2row, player2column;
        enum DONE {win1, win2, win3, win4, win5, win6, win7,win8,
                   win9, win10, win11, win12, win13, win14, win15, win16};


        //Default Constructor
        public TicTacToe(){
            board = new int [3,3] { {0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0} };
        }

        int win1 = 1;  

        public void PrintBoard(){
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------\n"+
                              "|       |       |       |\n"+
                              "|   {0}   |   {1}   |   {2}   |\n" +
                              "|_______|_______|_______|\n"+
                              "|       |       |       |\n"+
                              "|   {3}   |   {4}   |   {5}   |\n" +
                              "|_______|_______|_______|\n"+
                              "|       |       |       |\n"+
                              "|   {6}   |   {7}   |   {8}   |\n" +
                              "|_______|_______|_______|\n",
                              board[0,0],board[0,1],board[0,2],
                              board[1,0],board[1,1],board[1,2],
                              board[2,0],board[2,1],board[2,2]);
        }// end PrintBoard method

        public void Play(){
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Player 1's turn.");
                Console.Write("Player 1: Enter row ( 0 <= row < 3 ): "); //prompt user
                player1row = Console.ReadLine(); //get string from user           
                Console.Write("Player 1: Enter column ( 0 <= row < 3 ): "); //prompt user 
                player1column = Console.ReadLine(); //get string from user

                //Convert string to ints
                int p1r = Convert.ToInt32(player1row);
                int p1c = Convert.ToInt32(player1column);
                // assign marker to desired position
                board[p1r, p1c] = 1;

                PrintBoard(); // Update board
                checkWinner();

                Console.WriteLine("\nPlayer 2's turn.");
                Console.Write("Player 2: Enter row ( 0 <= row < 3 ): ");
                player2row = Console.ReadLine(); //get string from user     
                Console.Write("Player 2: Enter column ( 0 <= row < 3 ): ");
                player2column = Console.ReadLine(); //get string from user

                //Convert string to ints
                int p2r = Convert.ToInt32(player2row);
                int p2c = Convert.ToInt32(player2column);
                // assign marker to desired position
                board[p2r, p2c] = 2;

                PrintBoard(); // Update board
                checkWinner();

            }
        }//end Play method

        private bool checkWinner()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)

                    //I WANT TO CHECK FOR A WIN OR DRAW HERE BUT DONT KNOW HOW TO






    }}// end class
```

I want to check for a winner using 2 for loops, the first checking the rows, then another checking for columns, then adding 2 separate if statements to check the diagonals, but i really don't know how to & have been stuck for a while now.

Answer (score 3):

I wont code it for you but here is the logic you can use:

1) For each column check if all rows are the same, if yes declare winner. If not go to step 2.

2) For each row check if all column values are the same, if yes declare winner. If not go to step 3.

3) Now check diagonals, there are only two possibilities here [0,0] [1,1] [2,2] and  also [0,2] [1,1] [2,0] if they are the same declare winner, if not check whether all values in array are filled, if yes declare draw if not make users enter values.

Comment: See, this is where i'm kind of stuck though.  I don't know what to put in terms of checking it.  I ask the rows & columns from the user, convert their inputs to strings & put them on the board using 'board[p1r, p1c] =1 ' or 'board[p2r, p2c] = 2'.  I don't know what I would put to check for rows & columns.  I think I kinda confused my self.

Answer (score 3):

As [Iiya has said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21369329/80428), you're going to have to through through all the win cases. There's many ways to do that but the very gist of it in code would be

```
private bool checkWinner(int player)
{
    // check rows
    if (board[0, 0] == player && board[0, 1] == player && board[0, 2] == player) { return true; }
    if (board[1, 0] == player && board[1, 1] == player && board[1, 2] == player) { return true; }
    if (board[2, 0] == player && board[2, 1] == player && board[2, 2] == player) { return true; }

    // check columns
    if (board[0, 0] == player && board[1, 0] == player && board[2, 0] == player) { return true; }
    if (board[0, 1] == player && board[1, 1] == player && board[2, 1] == player) { return true; }
    if (board[0, 2] == player && board[1, 2] == player && board[2, 2] == player) { return true; }

    // check diags
    if (board[0, 0] == player && board[1, 1] == player && board[2, 2] == player) { return true; }
    if (board[0, 2] == player && board[1, 1] == player && board[2, 0] == player) { return true; }

    return false;
}
```

You can optimise this however which way you'd like (using for loops or matrices). Note the `checkWinner()` function requires a `player` input.

Comment: That's what i just figured out, but now the 'player' input is confusing me because i'm playing between 2 human players & not 1 player against the computer.

Comment: Or where/how do i declare player when it is 2 human players that are playing?

Comment: this method doesn't care if its human or computer who plays, it just checks if the given number exists in a winning format. in the play function just change `checkWinner()` line to     `if (checkWinner(1))
        Console.WriteLine("\nPlayer 1 has won");
    else if (checkWinner(2))
        Console.WriteLine("\nPlayer 2 has won");`

Comment: The important thing to note is that only the player that has just moved (no matter who, human/computer/whatever) is the only that can possibly won, so it will simplify to check just for that one.

Comment: thank you @jay that worked.  2 more quick questions though, for checking diagonals, would that be a different method that i would have to write?  or wold that still go in the checkWinner() method.  Also, how would i be able to stop/restart the game whenever a winner is crowned or there is a draw?

Comment: 1. there's already diagnal checks in the code I provided (see the last two lines under `// check diags`). 2. reset the values of your variables, for example iterate through `board` and set each cell to a reset value

Comment: @jay sorry, i didn't mean diagonals, i meant how would i check for a 'draw'?  & where would i iterate board?

Comment: in tic-tac-toe a draw is decided if all the cells are taken up but there's no winner. so when all the `board` cells have a value, and `checkWinner()` is false for both players it's a draw

Comment: Read my #3 for this user3238423, if all checks fail (meaning there is no winner) and all array values are full, declare a draw.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer how to detect the draw, as all others have focused only on checking if someone won.

The game can only be drawn when the board is fully completed, and no other winning combination is formed. So it's not difficult to detect after you checked for winner and haven't found one.

- Check for winner, if not found, continue detecting for ties.
- Scan the whole array of the board, no matter in what order.
- If found an empty spot, it's NOT a tie (further moves are possible), interrupt the loop and continue playing.
- Once you've reached the end of the loop, declare a draw (all spaces are filled without a winning combination).

Comment: Would checking for a draw be its own method or would it stay in the checkWinner() method?

Comment: Either way is fine. It must be done after CheckWinner finishes, so what I would have done is to create its own method, but call it from inside CheckWinner. More of OOP design practices rather than any technical reason or limitation really, and then just personal preference.

Comment: I tried something like this, but it's not working.           private bool checkDraw(int player)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    if (board[i, j] == player)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                  

                }
            } Console.WriteLine("Draw"); return false;
        }

Comment: You should check that `board[i,j]==empty` then return `false` (if there are empty spaces, it cannot be a draw yet). When the loop ends, return `true` instead.

Comment: I figured out & actually did it a different way to check if theres a draw.  I made the whole game in a for loop.  After each player makes a move, a counter is incremented by 1.  If there is no winner after 9 moves, since there are 9 spots on the board, i declare a draw.  This works, now all i need is to figure out how to end the game after a winner is declared because at the moment, even after there is a winner, the game still continues & prompts the next player to make their move.  Any pointers on how to do that?

Comment: what i said above is basically all i basically need to finish.  i tried adding Environment.exit(0); to checkWinner() but it just terminates the program as soon as someone makes a move then i just tried adding it after the 'if' statements that check if there's a winner & that also didn't work.

Comment: Nice trick, that would also work too. I suppose you need to check both the draw and the winner in the while loop condition. Try something like that `while(moves<9 && !CheckWinner(player))`, so that you keep going if the board is not full, but also interrupt everything when you found a winner.

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach is to try every square (for i = 0; i < 3; for j = 0; j < 3) then if that square is not blank go in every of the eight possible directions, counting each square with the same 'color' until you go off the board. If your count ever reaches the value three then you have a winner position for the color of the starting square.

Comment: I'm not quite sure i grasp your approach because I'm writing this as a console application.

Comment: I was trying to describe an algorithmic approach so the UI mode should not matter. I am out of time now but I will elaborate if you haven't figured it out tomorrow.