# Diagonal and Up/Down Tic Tac Toe Algorithm C# Wpf

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tic-tac-toe

So I have programmed the horizontal win for Tic Tac Toe, however I haven't been successful with the others.

Here is the code for the horizontal win.

```
 private void CheckWinner(int row, int col)
    {
        if (aIntNaughtsCrosses[row, 0] == aIntNaughtsCrosses[row, 1])
        {
            if (aIntNaughtsCrosses[row, 0] == aIntNaughtsCrosses[row, 2])
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Yay");
            }

         }
```

aIntNaughtsCrosses is the array.

```
 else if(aIntNaughtsCrosses[col, 0] == aIntNaughtsCrosses[row, 0])
        {
            if(aIntNaughtsCrosses[col, 0] == aIntNaughtsCrosses[row, 0])
            {
                if(aIntNaughtsCrosses[col, 0] == aIntNaughtsCrosses[row, 1])
                {
                    if(aIntNaughtsCrosses[col, 0] == aIntNaughtsCrosses[row, 2])
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("yay");
                    }
                }
            }


        }
```

That is the code I planned for the vertical/down win. With it also being applied to column 1 and 2.

Comment: `I haven't been successful with the others` - It sounds like you did give it a try, so please show what you tried for the vertical and the diagonal cases.

Comment: @PeterB ` else if(aIntNaughtsCrosses[col, 0] == aIntNaughtsCrosses[row, 0])
            {
                if(aIntNaughtsCrosses[col, 0] == aIntNaughtsCrosses[row, 0])
                {
                    if(aIntNaughtsCrosses[col, 0] == aIntNaughtsCrosses[row, 1])
                    {
                        if(aIntNaughtsCrosses[col, 0] == aIntNaughtsCrosses[row, 2])
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("yay");
                        }
                    }
                }
               
                
            }`

Comment: It seems very ineffectice as i would have to use this for column 1 and 2 aswell, if the code worked.

Comment: @Tburn96 please don't post relevant code as a comment. Edit your question instead to include that as formatted code

Comment: That is for the vertical

Comment: @Rafalon understood

Comment: From my unedrstanding ... it's TicTacToe so it's 3x3 grid system where you check if `{ grid[x = 0, y =0], grid[x, y + 1], grid[x, y + 2] }` `SequenceEquals('x')` or `SequnceEquals('o')`. It's easy game why do you want to make it so complex?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tic Tac Toe, Help/Determine Winner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369135/tic-tac-toe-help-determine-winner)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got it right for horizontal, keeping same row and making the column change.
Now, you have to keep the same column and make the row change to check for vertical:

```
if (aIntNaughtsCrosses[row, 0] == aIntNaughtsCrosses[row, 1] && // horizontal
    aIntNaughtsCrosses[row, 0] == aIntNaughtsCrosses[row, 2] || // horizontal
    aIntNaughtsCrosses[0, col] == aIntNaughtsCrosses[1, col] && // vertical
    aIntNaughtsCrosses[0, col] == aIntNaughtsCrosses[2, col])   // vertical
{
    MessageBox.Show("Yay");
}
```

This means:

> ```
> IF (row,0) equals (row,1) equals (row,2) OR   // horizontal
>    (0,col) equals (1,col) equals (2,col) THEN // vertical
> DISPLAY "Yay"
> ```

---

For diagonals, note that there are only 2 diagonals so you could do (shortening `aIntNaughtsCrosses` to `arr`):

```
if (col == row &&     // top-left to bottom-right
    arr[0, 0] == arr[1, 1] &&
    arr[0, 0] == arr[2, 2] ||
    col == 2 - row && // top-right to bottom-left
    arr[0, 2] == arr[1, 1] &&
    arr[0, 2] == arr[2, 0])
{
    MessageBox.Show("Yay");
}
```

This means:

> ```
> IF (row,col) is in diag1 AND (0,0) equals (1,1) equals (2,2) OR   // diag1
>    (row,col) is in diag2 AND (0,2) equals (1,1) equals (2,0) THEN // diag2
> DISPLAY "Yay"
> ```

---

In summary, the following should work:

```
if (arr[row, 0] == arr[row, 1] && // horizontal
    arr[row, 0] == arr[row, 2] ||
    arr[0, col] == arr[1, col] && // vertical
    arr[0, col] == arr[2, col] ||
    col == row &&     // top-left to bottom-right
    arr[0, 0] == arr[1, 1] &&
    arr[0, 0] == arr[2, 2] ||
    col == 2 - row && // top-right to bottom-left
    arr[0, 2] == arr[1, 1] &&
    arr[0, 2] == arr[2, 0])
{
    MessageBox.Show("Yay");
}
```

This means:

> ```
> IF (row,0) equals (row,1) equals (row,2) OR // horizontal 
>    (0,col) equals (1,col) equals (2,col) OR // vertical
>    (row,col) in diag1 AND (0,0) equals (1,1) equals (2,2) OR   // diag1
>    (row,col) in diag2 AND (0,2) equals (1,1) equals (2,0) THEN // diag2
> DISPLAY "Yay"
> ```

Comment: that makes sense, thank you, I have a thought process in my head for how to do diagonal, but it uses for nested if statements and stuff that seems very inefficient.

Comment: thats a very efficient way, I understand now, thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Actually, if you click in the corners, it wins straight away with no other moves made.

Comment: @Tburn96 I edited my answer to actually check if we're on the diagonal before telling we won that diagonal