# Exclude a value in a comparison

Tags: c#

I'm new to writing code and I'm starting with a TicTacToe game to introduce myself. So far I have this:

```
namespace TicTacToe
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string square1 = " ";
            string square2 = " ";
            string square3 = " ";
            string square4 = " ";
            string square5 = " ";
            string square6 = " ";
            string square7 = " ";
            string square8 = " ";
            string square9 = " ";

            bool playerIsX = true;
            string symbol = "X";

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" " + square1 + " | " + square2 + " | " + square3);
                Console.WriteLine("-----------");
                Console.WriteLine(" " + square4 + " | " + square5 + " | " + square6);
                Console.WriteLine("-----------");
                Console.WriteLine(" " + square7 + " | " + square8 + " | " + square9);

                if (playerIsX == true)
                {
                    Console.Write("X enter square: ");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("O enter square: ");
                }
                string square = Console.ReadLine();

                if (square == "1")
                {
                    square1 = symbol;
                }
                else if (square == "2")
                {
                    square2 = symbol;
                }
                else if (square == "3")
                {
                    square3 = symbol;
                }
                else if (square == "4")
                {
                    square4 = symbol;
                }
                else if (square == "5")
                {
                    square5 = symbol;
                }
                else if (square == "6")
                {
                    square6 = symbol;
                }
                else if (square == "7")
                {
                    square7 = symbol;
                }
                else if (square == "8")
                {
                    square8 = symbol;
                }
                else if (square == "9")
                {
                    square9 = symbol;
                }

                if (square1 == square2 & square2 == square3)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("You Win!");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                }
                else if (square1 == square4 & square4 == square7)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("You Win!");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                }
                if (square4 == square5 & square5 == square6)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("You Win!");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                }
                if (square7 == square8 & square8 == square9)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("You Win!");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                }
                if (square2 == square5 & square5 == square8)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("You Win!");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                }
                if (square3 == square6 & square6 == square9)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("You Win!");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                }
                if (square1 == square5 & square5 == square9)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("You Win!");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                }
                if (square3 == square5 & square5 == square7)
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("You Win!");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                }

                Console.Clear();
                playerIsX = !playerIsX;
                if (playerIsX == true)
                {
                    symbol = "X";
                }
                else
                {
                    symbol = "O";
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I know it's beefy but I'm only trying to get a basic understanding so I can move on from there. Currently for the winning I compare three values, but since they're all spaces, at the start of the game multiple possibilities already trigger the win. Is there a way to exclude a value, say space?
Thanks.

Comment: You are comparing strings with `==` but you should be using the `string.Equals()` method if you want to compare the contents of the strings.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @JacobHuckins What? This is not Java.

Comment: *Is there a way to exclude a value, say space* - `if (square1 != " " && square1 == square2 && square2 == square3)`?

Comment: @JacobHuckins `String.Equals()` and `operator==` for `System.String` perform value comparison. If you want to see if two strings are the same object, you use `ReferenceEquals()`.

Comment: @JacobHuckins Please don't spread [misinformation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1659107/11683).

Comment: @JacobHuckins: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659097/why-would-you-use-string-equals-over

Comment: for tic tac toe, I guess the best way to write your code is using a matrix. Check the values for lines and columns + main diagonal and antidiagonal to see if it's a win.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tic Tac Toe, Help/Determine Winner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369135/tic-tac-toe-help-determine-winner)

Comment: @GSerg @MariusBancila @Xaqron My bad, came from Java background and didn't read the top answer to the link I posted saying it was a common mistake Java people make. Now i'm kind of annoyed I've been typing out `.Equals()` every time I needed to compare strings.

Answer (score 1):

In your specific situation, you have a common field in each `if` statement - a field is always evaluated twice as such:

```
if (square4 == square5 & square5 == square6)
{
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("You Win!");
    Console.ReadLine();
    break;
}
```

`square5` is evaluated against both square4, and square6, so we can definitely argue that if `square5` is **not** equal to `" "`, this statement will not pass.

From there, you could easily just implement a quick check:

```
if (square4 == square5 & square5 == square6 && square5 != " ")
{
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("You Win!");
    Console.ReadLine();
    break;
}
```

I would highly suggest you look into developing a more readable, and elegant piece of code for what you're doing though, good luck on your learning journey!

Answer (score 0):

The quickest (not best) way to do it would be to check for a space in your comparison. That means this
`if (square1 == square2 & square2 == square3)`
would turn into
`if (square1 == square2 & square2 == square3 & square3 != " ")`